# Блог на Modx Revo. Есть ли аналог ditto для Revo?

Tags: modx, сниппет, блог

Это мой первый проект на modx. Нужно реализовать блог. Нашел прекрасный и до боли простой сниппет ditto, но незадача в том, что он не поддерживается на Revo. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь аналог или подходящую версию этого сниппета, если такая существует. Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 0):

По сути вам нужно выводить список ресурсов(что делает Ditto), с этим прекрасно справится [pdoResources](https://docs.modx.pro/komponentyi/pdotools/snippetyi/pdoresources) из пакета pdoTools.